# Scrollbar on Parent window disappears when size of the popup grows

Tags: html, css

As the size of the popup grows, the lower portion of the popup cannot be seen even if scrollbar is present. The scrollbar on the parent window should adjust automatically with the growing popup so that scrolling can be done to view the lower portion of the popup.

Comment: Do you think anyone can help you without looking at your code? Paste your code here to see what you tried.

Comment: Consider it as a generic code..there is a popup with few dropdowns. On selecting multiple values from dropdowndows (values keep on appending below the dropdowns) the popup grows downwards and lower portion is not visible. I just want the scrollbar of the parent window to be scrollable so that I can see the whole popup.

Answer (score 0):

With out code its very difficult to say

make parent

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```